# Lua, Require, Available Functions

Tags: lua, require

If I `require` three included files in my Lua script, can any function in any one of those files then see (and most importantly, call) any of the other functions ?

I'm running into the problem of functions calling functions which call other functions. I tried to put the various functions in other files, and then `include` them instead of writing them into the main file.

I *think* it's working, my tests are convincing if not conclusive.

My mainline code does this...

```
 require "SOME_REQUIRED_FILE_01"
 require "SOME_REQUIRED_FILE_02"
 require "SOME_REQUIRED_FILE_03"

 XYZ = 0

 File_02_Function_A()
```

I looked on [The Lua Site](http://www.Lua.org) and found [THIS PAGE](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html) but I'm not totally clear on it.

Can ***EVERY*** function in *all three*  required files see **EVERY OTHER** function in all three files ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`require` is basically the same as `dofile`, except for mechanisms that avoid loading the same file multiple times (and some other useful things like loaders). That means, that they can set global variables (though they should not) as well. So, if you set a global variable in one of the required files, the global can be seen in the entire scope of the require function. That means in other required files as well.

Having said that, it is not best practise to set global variables in `required` files. It is better to return a table that has functions and variables exported by the module inside. Then you would call those functions like this:

```
local some_required_file_01 = require "SOME_REQUIRED_FILE_01"
local some_result_01 = some_required_file_01.some_function_01()
```

Comment: Can a function in the 1st required file call a function in the 3rd required file ?  My problem was functions calling functions that had not yet been encountered in execution, resulting in a function call to a nil value.

Comment: In general, yes, but it can only be called once the third file has been loaded. Please note that the same can be achieved if you follow the advice of not setting any globals. You can require the third file in the main file, but you can also require the same file in the first file and call the functions locally. It is much cleaner and require makes sure that you don't load the file twice.

Comment: Thanks, got it.  Clicked twice on your answer.